# Bootstrap-framework - col-sm - grid for small screens doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, col

I've been trying a lot of things but couldn't find the solution to my problem.

I want to align 3 different parts in a certain way for all kind of screens but *col-sm* and *col-xs* from bootstrap are not working.

I've tried this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            a           
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            b
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            c
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it only displays on the same line for large and medium screens, not on small screens.

The only way I've found to make it work was to write *col* instead of *col-sm-4* but if I do so, I can't manipulate the grid exactly as I would like

Comment: there is no `col-xs`, you should start with the small view as `col-` then only include the class when columns change. So, `col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6` should be `col-md-4 col-6`. You dont have to define every breakpoint if there is no change

Answer (score 4):

To solve the problem when the width is less than **576px**, you should apply the `col-4` style.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            a           
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            b
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
            c
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no `col-xs`, the OP want those as the less than 576px, so it should be `col-4`, `col-6`, then last column is `col-2`

Comment: @zgood I noticed. I didn't specify this detail as I was only focusing on the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it's working quite well !
Do you know why we have to add this and why col-sm is not working as expected ?

Comment: I understand, I just thought it was worth a mention as it does relate to the problem - he was using the wrong `col` class

Comment: @Reminder If you examine the table, the col-sm style is valid when the screen width is between 576px and 720px.

Comment: @Sercan Oh ok, so I had obviously to refer to "Extra small" screen for my problem and col-xs doesn't exist anymore, that's why it was not working. Thanks a lot !